# Rails sunspot: re-indexing of an associated model does not run as a delayed job

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job, sunspot-rails

I am using sunspot in combination with delayed job to perform re-indexing of my models as an asynchronous background process. For model updates this works fine due to: `handle_asynchronously :solr_index, :queue => 'solr_index'`.

However, the searchable block within the model (let's call it model A) also references attributes of an associated model (B), where B has many As. When the associated model becomes updated by the user, I trigger re-indexing within an after_save callback in B like so: `Sunspot.index(self.my_many_As)`. While re-indexing is successful, it does not run as a delayed job. How can I accomplish that?

Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't think you need to handle re-indexing for sunspot, that should be handle each time you commit changes.  Sounds like you need model B to touch model A.  in ModelB Class: belongs_to :modelA, touch: true, that will update the updated_at field an therefore trigger an update of the index for that with solr.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @symana. However, setting updated_at for A when actually B becomes updated is - at least within my application context - somewhat misleading. Moreover, only a small subset of Bs' attributes is relevant when indexing A. Hence the result would be a considerable amount of superfluous update calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of calling `Sunspot.index(self.my_many_As)` I call solr_index for each A directly inside B's after_save callback `self.my_many_As.each(&:solr_index)`. Works for me.

Answer (score 1):

How about you schedule a job that calls the index on the updated documents? You can log last time index for specific model was updated, and call Sunspot.index(ModelB.updated_after(last_update_time))

Comment: Thanks @BasharAbdullah, but I think I found a cleaner solution (see post below).